# Does anyone know a tool for Aspect-Oriented modeling

Tags: uml, aop

We are doing some research on Aspect-Oriented design and analysis. We are looking for a tool which integrates UML profile and supports AO modeling. I found some relevant papers, but none publishes an available tool. Does anyone know a tool that we can use? Thanks.

Comment: There are on stackoverflow some questions about java annotations and UML, do they help you ?

Comment: I scanned the questions, and I don't think those questions are helpful. One is really relevant to mine, but no answer yet.

Comment: Which one ? For my understanding aspect progamming is like adding annoations to java class. And a simple solution for annotation is to create a stereotype of Interface, formally it is needed to create a profil for that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_software_development

Comment: @granier Yes, we tried aspect programming. But what we want to do is  automated programming based on MDA. So we need to design a model firstly. I know there are some work about the AO UML Profile, and someone mentions tools in their publication. I believe that there must be available tools. So I post this question.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Thanks. I checked wiki before I posted my question and hoped to find answer. But no lucky.

Comment: I think it probably depends on what elements of AOP analysis and design you're thinking of. You could do most software constructs using UML as is, maybe with stereotypes and tagged values of your own if you need to extend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a tool I can use. It is JAC http://jac.ow2.org/. I will try it firstly.